# Serving an iframe from a React app - how do I set Content Security Policy frame-ancestors?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, aws-amplify, content-security-policy

I am offering a third party website the option to embed an iframe from my React app. I want to make sure only whitelisted domains can embed iframes from our app. How do I do that?

For example: React app runs on localhost:3000 (or app.ourdomain.com). partnerdomain.com loads an iframe from app.ourdomain.com. This should only load for partnerdomain.com, but not for otherdomain.com.

I believe 'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors 'self' https://app.ourdomain.com https://partnerdomain.com;" is the solution but I don't know where to put this Or perhaps there is a better / different way?

I've tried the meta tag (doesn't apply to frame-ancestors), headers on the axios calls, and even the backend (Django). None work or make a difference.

The React app is hosted on AWS Amplify if this makes a difference.